# Logging module not working in python 2.6.6

Tags: python, logging, python-2.6

Below code is working fine on Python 2.7 but unfortunately i have to deploy my script on Linux 5.9 which has python 2.6.6 installed in it and there is no option for me to upgrade. I am not able to make logging work on python 2.6.6

```
import logging

class Test():
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args

    def call_this(self):
        logger.info("Info Log %s" % self.args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test("Hello")
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    file_formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(levelname)-1s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s")
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('LogFile.log')
    file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)
    logger.setLevel("INFO")
    t.call_this()
```

Comment: Consider that Python 2.6 is ancient, and most people will not have it available anymore. In how far is the logging module not working? What error do you get when running this code?

Comment: While the self-answer is fine, I really question the need for a Stack Overflow question specific to Python 2.6 support. If you are referring to CentOS 5.9, *that* reached end-of-life 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed below line of code and now it works.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```